# _layouts/muisetng.aspx change language page link is missing from site settings

Tags: 2013, language-pack

_layouts/muisetng.aspx change language page link is missing from site settings page
i have installed share pint 2013 with Arabic language pack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it came after re-install language pack and run sharepoint configuration wizard thanks